# Given boundaries, find interval

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Having a list like this

```
[207, 357, 470, 497, 537]
```

where each number denotes the boundary of an interval (`0` being implicit at the beginning of the list), what is **a pythonic way** of finding out to which interval a given number `n` belongs to?

So the intervals are

```
0: (0, 207)
1: (208, 357)
2: (358, 497)
3: (498, 537)
```

If `n=0`, then the corresponding interval is `0`, for `n=360`, it's `2`.

Comment: do you mean to say "how do I find out which interval an number sits in"...

Comment: bisect seems answer but please reword your question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) of course:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> lst = [207, 357, 470, 497, 537]
>>> bisect.bisect_left(lst, 0)
0
>>> bisect.bisect_left(lst, 360)
2
```

The module uses [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which requires a sorted sequence. With such a sequence you can divide the sequence in half by picking an index mid-way between the first and last, to see if the value you need is in either half. You then continue dividing the selected half until you found a matching insertion point. That lets you find the insertion point in O(log N) time for a sequence of length N, i.e. very fast.

Comment: +1 *of course* for you, but not for mortals like me!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'll try to keep that in mind when I have a Delphi question. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy` and [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

boundaries = [207, 357, 497, 537]
values = [0, 207, 300, 500, 9999]

np.searchsorted(intervals, values)
```

This gives:

```
>>> array([0, 0, 1, 3, 4])
```

(if the value `207` was instead intended to belong to the interval `1` , `side='right'` could be used)

Comment: Using np.searchsorted is way faster. I prefer this answer to the accepted one.