# General python function with many interval cases that returns specific values depending on interval

Tags: python, function, intervals

I am having problems with writing a function in Python that based on an input x outputs a y depending on in what interval the input x is in. As of currently the code looks like this

```
def getPowerLimit(x):
                    if 0.009 <= x <= 380.2:
                        return -39
                    elif 380.2 < x <= 389.8:
                        return -94
                    elif 389.8 < x <= 390.2:
                        return -39
                    elif 390.2 < x <= 399.8:
                        return -60
                    elif 399.8 < x <= 410.2:
                        return -39
```

And this needs to proceed with differing intervals up to around 12000. Each with differing return values which means I will have alot of different cases. This can certainly not be the best approach for this problem so I was wondering if there is a different and quicker way to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given boundaries, find interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942698/given-boundaries-find-interval)

Comment: @dlask Not totally, there's also a return value for each interval here.

Comment: I guess it seems similar..But yea there is a very specific return value for the intervals in my case :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is suggested by dlask's comment in your question, you can make use of the `bisect` library:

```
boundaries = [0.009, 380.2, 389.8, 390.2, 399.8, 410.2]
values = [None, -39, -94, -39, -60, -39, None]

# what you need
import bisect
values[bisect.bisect_left(boundaries, x)]
```

Assume you can construct `boundaries` and `values` with some external sources like CSV.

Comment: Modified list of `values` allows us to avoid the "minus one" part: `[None, -39, -94, -39, -60, -39, None]`.

Comment: @Gall Well, OK, but values out of the whole interval don't seem to be defined.

Comment: Wow this was really neat. Thanks a bundle!

Comment: @dlask You're actually right. I wrongly looked at the special case for the first interval in OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement binary search for this: (NOTE: use it as psuado code, it may contains bugs):

```
intervals = [0.009, 380.2, 389.8, 390.2, 399.8, 410.2]
values = [-39, -94, -39, -60, -39]


def binary_serach(x, intervals, values):
    if len(values) == 1:
        return values[0]
    i = len(intervals) / 2

    if x < intervals[i]:
        return binary_serach(x, intervals[:i], values[:i]):
    if x >= intervals[i]:
        return binary_serach(x, intervals[i:], values[i:]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the limits as a list of tuples:

```
# [((low,hight),result),...]

limits = [((0.009, 380.2),-39), ((380.2,389.8),-94),...]
```

Then it's easy to add new limits and to check if a given `x` is in a range of limits.