# Check whether coordinates are in a certain region on a coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a coordinate system with a certain amount of regions, similar to this one:
[image: coordinate system]

The difference in my case is however, that all regions are uniquely numbered, are all of the same size and there are 16 of them (so each quadrant would have 4 slices of exactly the same size).

I also have a set of tuples (two dimensional coordinates), which are all between (-1,-1) and (1,1). I'd now like to check into which region  (i.e. 1 to 16) they'd land if mapped onto the coordinate system.

As a total beginner, I have no idea on how to tackle this, but here is my approach so far:

**Make all the dividing lines functions and check for each point whether they're above and below them. Ignore those on the decision boundary**

For example: Quadrant 1 has four regions. From the x-axis to the y-axis (counter-clockwise) let's call them a, b, c and d.

a would be the region between the x-axis and f1(x) = 0.3333x (red)

b between f1 and f2, f2(x) = x (yellow)

c between f2 and f3, f3(x) = 3x (blue)

d between f3 and the y-axis

[image: graphs]

As code:

```
def a(p):
   if(y > 0 and y < 0.3333x):
      return "a"
   else:
      b(p)

def b(p):
   if(y > 0.3333x and y < x)
      return "b"
   else:
      c(p)

def c(p):
   if(y > x and y < 3x):
      return "c"
   else: 
      d(p)

def d(p): 
   if(y > 3x and x > 0):
      return "d"
```

Note: for readability's sake I just wrote "x" and "y" for the tuple's respective coordinates, instead p[0] or p[1] every time. Also, as stated above, I'm assuming that there are not items directly on the functions, so those are ignored.

Now, that is a possible solution, but I feel like there's almost certainly a more efficient one.

Comment: Are you looking for a ready-made library for cartesian shape operations?

Comment: Maybe? I don't know to be honest. I just feel like defining 16 very similar functions in order to find out where a point lands on a plane seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working between `(-1,-1)` and `(1,1)` coordinates and divinding equaly the cartesian plane, it becomes naturally to use trigonometry functions. Thinking in the unitary circle, which has `2*pi` deegres, you are dividing it in `n` equal parts (in this case `n = 16`). So each slice has `(2*pi)/16 = pi/8` deegres. Now you can imagine an arbitray point `(x, y)` connected to the origin point `(0, 0)`, it formes an angle with the x-axis. To find this angle you just need to calculate the arc-tangent of `y/x`. Then you just need to verify in which angle section it is.

Here is a sketch:

[image: sketch]

And to directly map to the interval you can use the [bisect module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942698/given-boundaries-find-interval):

```
import bisect
from math import atan2
from math import pi

def find_section(x, y):

    # create intervals
    sections = [2 * pi * i / 16 for i in range(1, 17)]

    # find the angle
    angle = atan2(y, x)

    # adjusts the angle to the other half circle
    if y < 0:
        angle += 2*pi

    # map into sections
    return bisect.bisect_left(sections, angle)
```

**Usage:**

```
In [1]: find_section(0.4, 0.2)
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: find_section(0.8, 0.2)
Out[2]: 0
```

Comment: Damn, I was actually thinking of dividing the plane into pi/8 and working with the angles, but couldn't think of how to it in Python. Excellent! That's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: This is much better. I'll leave my answer up for reference.

Comment: While implementing I found a little flaw, as your solution only returns sections in the first quadrant. The "correct" solution to my problem would be: `angle = atan2(y,x) 
    
    if(y < 0):
        angle = angle + 2 * pi`

Comment: @Readler well noted! Added to solution.

Answer (score 1):

Shapely is a python library that can help you with typical cartesian geometry, but as far as I know it doesn't have an easy way of extending its `Line` objects indefinitely based on a function.

If you're ok with that, then you can check if any `Point` is in any `Polygon` using the `Polygon.contains(Point)` pattern, as shown here: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.contains

Comment: > it doesn't have an easy way of extending its Line objects indefinitely based on a function.  

Fortunately that's not needed, as all my points are in one area (between (-1,-1) and (1,1))! `object.within(p)` seems better suited, though.  So my new approach would be to create 16 polygons (corresponding to my 16 regions), and then check in which regions a point lands (with `within`). Sounds a lot better than my approach!