# Getting the level of a score referenced from a list Python

Tags: python

I have a set of data which represent the grade or level of a specific value.

```
scores = [90, 70, 60, 50, 40]
```

So '90' above means the score is 90 out of 100, '70' is 70 out of 100.
And the first element of the list `scores[0]` is grade A.
The second element `scores[1]` is grade B.

So I want to input the score from user like `yourMark = int(input('Enter your mark: '))`
And i want to return the corresponding  grade of the mark.

Like:

```
Enter your mark: 50
Your grade is D

Enter your mark: 35
You failed

Enter your mark: 74
Your grade is B

Enter your mark: 69
Your grade is C

Enter your mark: 92
Your grade is A
```

I have no clue how to do that properly.
I used some stupid way like getting each value of the list and assigning it to a variable.   Then compare the value with the input value by a bunch of if statement.

However there are more than one scores list in my program. Using the way that I tried is time-consuming and not  practical.
And I want to work with list but not assigning new variables. So i wonder what is the better way to do this.

Appreciate if you guys could help :)

My stupid attempt

```
marks = [90, 70, 60, 50, 40]

yourMark = int(input('Enter your mark: '))


def grade(mark):
    markA = marks[0]
    markB = marks[1]
    markC = marks[2]
    markD = marks[3]
    markE = marks[4]

    if mark >= markA:
        print('Your grade is A')
    elif mark >= markB and mark <= markA:
        print('Your grade is B')
    elif mark >= markC and mark <= markB:
        print('Your grade is C')
    elif mark >= markD and mark <= markC:
        print('Your grade is D')
    elif mark >= markE and mark <= markD:
        print('Your grade is E')
    else:
        print('You failed')


grade(yourMark)
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store the scores and their corresponding grades. scores_dict = {90:"A",70:"B" ...}  something like this and workaround a logic beyond it.

Comment: Paste your attempt here.

Comment: I updated my attempt in the question

Comment: @WanDur : Use try/except like so to avoid non-numeric entries : 
`try:
        yourMark = int(input('Enter your mark: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another library (which is very widespread in Python world), you can use `numpy`. With that it's quite easy:

```
import numpy as np

def scores_to_marks(scores, scores_thresholds, marks):
    marks_indices = np.digitize(scores, scores_thresholds)
    return marks[marks_indices]
    
marks = np.array(['F','E','D','C','B','A'])
scores_thresholds = [40, 50, 60, 70, 90]
scores = [0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
print(scores_to_marks(scores, scores_thresholds, marks))

# answer
# ['F' 'F' 'F' 'F' 'F' 'E' 'D' 'C' 'B' 'B' 'A' 'A']
```

The idea is that `scores_thresholds` is a *sorted* array that defines so called "bins". Then `scores` is an array of arbitrary length, that defines numbers that belongs to some bins. `numpy.digitize` function finds the indices of bins, and using these indices we index the array of marks

Comment: There's much [better solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942715/11747148).

Comment: Thank you so much, it's definitely okay to use another library in my program

Comment: @Shayan, uses the standard library, indeed. But is it better in terms of coding? Numpy would suit better if the person really has a lot of scores to convert

Comment: But `bisect` uses binary search. There isn't any better algorithm for this purpose.

Comment: @Skayan Numpy obviously uses binary search in `np.digitize`, just more efficiently, from C++ vectorized code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use pandas DataFrame for getting an overview about your different scores lists and use another input field so that you can choose your scores list.

You can do it this way:

`import pandas as pd`

```
#input fields
yourMark = int(input('Enter your mark: '))
yourScoresList = input('Enter your Scores List: ')
```

in the second input field you have to fill in exactly the name of your scores list you want to use, I called the lists 'scoresList1' and 'scoresList2' as an example.

```
# initialize DataFrame
scoresDict = pd.DataFrame()
scoresDict['grades'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
scoresDict = scoresDict.set_index(['grades'])

# insert your several scores lists
scoresDict['scoresList1'] = [90,70,60,50,40]            # your scores list
scoresDict['scoresList2'] = [80,60,50,40,30]            # another example scores list
scoresDict # here you can visualize your table
```

And in the end you can assign the grades for example this way:

```
for grade in scoresDict.index:
    if yourMark >= scoresDict[yourScoresList][grade]:
        print('Your grade is ', grade)
        break
    if yourMark < scoresDict[yourScoresList]['E']:
        print('You failed')
```